# What's really behind an assignment in Emacs lisp?

Tags: elisp, variables, let-binding, setq

[Warning : these are noob questions.]

I'm a beginner in Emacs Lisp and I would like to be sure that I understand well what I'm really doing when I set a value to a variable with `setq` or `let`.

Here is a piece of code:

```lisp
(setq x '(1 2 3 4))     ; define x
(setq y x)              ; define y
(setcar y 9)            ; modify CAR of y
y                       ; -> (9 2 3 4): y has changed (ok)
x                       ; -> (9 2 3 4): but x has changed too!
```

1. It seems that when you define a symbol and give it the value of *another symbol*, this basically means that the two symbols become the same object?

   ```lisp
   (eq x y)             ; -> t
   ```

   (I expected that the instruction `(setq y x)` would make an "independant copy" of `x`, as it would be the case if you do `y <- x` in R language for example. Or, more formally, I thought this instruction would only fill the "value cell" of `y` by evaluating `(symbol-value 'x)`, but without "binding" those two objects together.)
2. This is really a matter of pointers, if I understand well. `(setq y x)`creates a new symbol which is basically bound to the same address as `x`? (I.e., `y` points towards `x` which points towards a given value, and so if you modify `y`, you will also modify `x` because both of them point towards the same address "by transitivity"?)
3. [Robert Chassell's book](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Lists-diagrammed.html) says that "*when a Lisp variable is set to a value, it is provided with the address of the list to which the variable refers*", but I cannot figure out what this means formally (where is this address stored?). A Lisp symbol is made of 4 components (name, value, function, properties). So, when I do `(setq y x)`, the "value cell" of `y` is really an *address* / a pointer towards `x`?

Comment: Great question. It is confusing for us noobs.

Comment: This is the same behavior as seen in Python (and other dynamic languages). There is an extra step in going from a variable to the value. Variables don't have the address of values, they have the address of a spot in memory that holds the address of the value.  So x = y doesn't copy the value, it copies the address of the spot in memory which holds the address of the value. Don't know about EmacsLisp, but Python has a way of duplicating the value so x and y can't refer to seoarate lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setq` is doing like expected, the thing here is, that `(1 2 3 4)` is not a value, so it is not what you think it is.

- a Place is a location in memory.
- `x` and `y` are Symbols.
- a Symbol merely points to a place. So `x` points to (the first `cons` of) your list.
- `(1 2 3 4)` is a List of `cons`es (aka a "chain" of `cons`es).
- `(1 2 3 4)` is not a value, but multiple chained values.
- a list is constructed like this `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil)))`.
- a cons consists of two pointers (car . cdr) to the places where the values are stored.
- a cons by itself is stored at a place. (*I'm not perfectly sure with that one*)

What did you do?:

- your new `y` points, after `setq` to the same place like `x`, because you said: point to the list referenced by symbol `x`.
- You changed the content of your list, which exists only once in memory.

I hope I got that right. :)

Good question, btw.

Comment: Most of what you say is right, IMO. But `(1 2 3 4)` **is** a value. It's a list of 4 elements. Don't confuse Lisp values with their implementation or manipulation. Same thing for a string, for example: `"1 2 3 4"` is a single (string) value. But you can access any elements of the string. Yes, element access is different in the cases of a string, which is an array/vector, and a list. But they are both Lisp values.

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks!
So I think it's even worse than I expected: I also misunderstood what is really a list! Because the behavior is different if we execute the three instructions `(setq x "a")`, `(setq y x)` and `(setq y "b")`: this time, `x` remains unchanged after those three instructions. If I understand well, this is simply because (unlike with those simple character values) lists involve *pointers*.

Comment: Yes, it is confusing. No two ways about it. Did you try with strings? Why are they not "addresses" then?... Is a string a list of chars... I shall get my cape... ;)

Comment: @Drew what I ment to say: `(1 2 3 4)` is not a single value, but multiple values. Thats different to arrays. Would you agree with that?

Comment: No, it's a single value. The value is a list. A list is implemented as either the atom `nil` or a cons cell whose cdr is a list. Think string or vector - similar concepts apply: `[1 2 3]` is a single value, a vector. The  vector has 3 elements, which are integer values.